# How is $false_a$ a character in a topos?

Tags: topos-theory

I am currently reading Goldblatt's Topoi, A categorial analysis of logic, and on p.117 there is exercise 3 where we have to show that $false_a$ is the character for $0_a$. There is a hint recommending to use the PBL. So far I've come to the following diagram :

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0 @>!>> 1 \\
@V 0_a V V @VV true V\\
a @>>false_a> \Omega \\
@V I_a V V @VV {1_\Omega} V \\
1 @> false >> \Omega
\end{CD}

Clearly the outer rectangle is a pullback, and in order to conclude with the PBL, I want to show that the down square is also a pullback, but I'm stuck there. Does anyone have a hint as to why this is the case ?

Thanks

Comment: The lower square is not a pullback. The pullback of an isomorphism is an isomorphism, but $a \to 1$ is not usually an isomorphism. You need to think about a different diagram, one where the lower square _is_ a pullback.

Comment: Thanks, I see now clearly how it couldn't be a pullback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a square whose two paths are $0\to 0\to 1$ and $0\overset{0_a}{\to} a\to 1$ (and picture the first of these as the left and bottom sides of a square). I claim that this is a pullback, since if we are given $f:x\to 0$ and $g:x\to a$ with $$x\overset{f}{\to}0\to 1=x\overset{g}{\to}a\to 1,$$ the existence of a morphism $x\to 0$ immediately means that $x$ is also initial, and there is a unique morphism $x\to 0$ filling in the pullback diagram for very silly reasons.

Combine this with the pullback square that defines $false$ and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, that's the diagram I finally ended up considering.